# Drywall skimcoating

Tags: drywall, painting, patching-drywall

Is this wall finish considered Level 3 or Level 4 Drywall? The place was built in 1980s, and has very unsmooth appearance, compared to newer places. Just curious if skimcoat would help, and if has to be Level 5 finish? A drywall contractor said Level 5 is very expensive to conduct. I am trying to do a job with the proper budget.

[image]

Comment: Would say someone put a textual finish on the wall.  Drywall itself should be flat/smooth.

Comment: We can't tell what quality finish your wall is from the photo. You could skim it and get it to look acceptable. Level 5 is for picky people, problematic lighting and higher gloss paints.

Answer (score 2):

That is a textured finish called "orange peel". It is typically applied over a level 3 finish (taped, a build up coat or "blocked", then skimmed and sanded), and is usually sprayed on by one means or another.

If you small repairs needing to be touched up , it is available in aerosol cans.

If you want to cover the texture, and have a smooth wall, then skim coating everything, which pretty much a level 5 finish , is your only option. Well, there are other options, but that will be your cheapest route if you want smooth wall.

Comment: I just bought a house that's damn close to this in the basement.   Drives me bonkers.   Why?   Why?   Good answer.   You could edit it a little though... Probably a level 3 but who knows because it is covered up with a thick texture!

Comment: @DMoore  Texture finishes are used a LOT out here in the NW. In MD where I am from originally, level 3 was used most of the time with level 5 on occasion. I have observed many a texture applied since I have been out here and it all starts with a level 3 finish. At first when I got here I thought it was a way of "cheating" to hide crappy work or incomplete finishing work, a shortcut in other words. But the finished level 3 walls I have seen this texture sprayed on would have been a great smooth wall finish all by itself

Answer (score -2):

no it is not level 5.  level 5 looks almost perfectly smooth.

Comment: Could you add some sort of reference, maybe, to support your statement? That would go a long way toward helping.